# Nuance / NDEV text-to-speech [import sound file]

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, audio

I'm trying to develop an app where as soon as the nuance text to speech "vocalizer" is completed an audio .wav file is generated on the android phone. Can anyone let me know how to do this. Here's a sample of my code:

```
static Vocalizer voc;
voc = _speechKit.createVocalizerWithLanguage("en_US", vocalizerListener, new Handler());
String value = "This is a sample Text";
voc.speakString(value, getApplication().getApplicationContext());
//here I want to import the audio file from the "void speakString()"
```

Answer (score 0):

In NMDP SpeechKit they dont have the ability to control the audio capture and playback.However there is an option available through their PS team to provide an interface for you to be able to do so .

if you want you can contact them asking for the interface

Also,
if you are using the stock android TTS there is a method called SynthesizeToFile() that should do what you are asking for